# No module named 'pandas' despite it's clearly installed?

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry I know this has been asked several times on the forum but I'm not quite able to debug this problem. Basically I would like to run my snakefile (using snakemake), but it's not recognising pandas from the line 'import pandas as pd'. I'm able to see it when I type 'pip show pandas', or 'pip3 show pandas'. It's also up to date according to 'conda update pandas' which says 'All requested packages already installed'. Just wondering if anyone has any idea other than reinstalling the whole python/anaconda?

Thanks!

Comment: In python, You could check sys.exectuable to see which python you are running. sys.path will tell you which paths are used to search for modules. And poke around functions in the `site` module to get info. pip and conda is competators. Sometimes they will not agree on what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with snakefile, but this sounds like the pandas install location isn't in the process' PATH environment variable.

As a user, terminal sessions usually load the profiles automatically such as ~/.bash_profile,. ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc (UNIX-like, Windows would have something similar), but for spawned processes they often don't inherit the environment variables and have to be explicitly checked and added to the PATH.

This is where virtual environments, such as venv, come in really handy for version control in python because instead of having to edit the PATH yourself you can use the command (unix):

```sh
source my_venv/bin/activate
```

which handles all the PATH and install locations of python packages for you.

To help more I would need more details about which OS you use and which (if any) virtual environment software you use, otherwise you can probably figure it out by reading the snakefile documentation related to python/conda virtual environments and environment variables.

I've found this question, which sounds like a similar problem and cause:

[Using pyenv in a snakemake rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316075/using-pyenv-in-a-snakemake-rule)

If you can add a command to the snakefile to activate your virtual environment, or you might be able to just add the path to your python environment's bin directory in the PATH for the snakefile. For example, if I have a virtual environment a the location /home/my_user/my_env, I should be able to simply add "/home/my_user/my_env/bin" to the PATH to get access to the installed python packages in that environment.